# Iteration through elements in different wrappers fails

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

Form has multiple elements in it and 5 of them are required to fill in. When failed to do so, these fields light up in red and  becomes (All the same class name). 1 element is in one wrapper, 2 elements are child for form and other 2 are in different wrapper so iterating with nth-child() does not work properly. 
I have errorData array where I store text values of these fields. Problem seems to be in var elementCss = '.error'; as it seems it takes only the first element's value. But I don't know how to go through all error objects that I have found..

Everything for the first element of .error is fine, but I need to check them all from the array.

```
var errorData = ['Client', 'Project name', 'Project code', 'Project stream', 'Project service line'];

iterateForm: function() {
  return this
  .waitForElementVisible('.error', load_speed)
  .api.elements('css selector', '.error',function (elements) {
    for (i = 0; i < elements.value.length; i++) {
      var elementCss = '.error';
      this.assert.containsText(elementCss, errorData[i]);
    }
  });
}

Element <.error> was visible after 1350 milliseconds.
✔ Testing if element <.error> contains text: "Client".
✖ Testing if element <.error> contains text: "Project name".  - expected "Project name" but got: "Client"
```

Comment: Searching for solution, but apparently I can't find answer.. Maybe my google skills are bad. Searching for any ideas, it can be not optimal.

Comment: You'll need to post a link to the page or the relevant HTML for the 5 elements.